Azure Private Endpoint on OnPremise machine
I've been trying to resolve an issue for days that I think may be a name resolution issue. I have an Azure Cognitive (OCR) resource to which I've associated a Private Endpoint. In addition, I have an on-premise machine that is connected to the Azure VNet via an S2S VPN.
It happens that when I try to attack the Private Endpoint from the OnPremise machine, I get an SSL certificate error:
Failed to reach billing endpoint: 'The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.'. Trying 9 more times.
The /etc/hosts file on the machine contains the FQDN and private IP of the Private Endpoint.
To summarize, I am having trouble attacking a Private Endpoint for Cognitive Services from an OnPremise machine connected to the Azure VNet via S2S VPN, either through xxxxxx.cognitiveservices.azure.com or xxxxxx.privatelink.cognitiveservices.azure.com
Do you know what could be happening? Thanks in advance
